# How to hide roles in user edit page?

Tags: users

I have a user registration page where in being a admin i have assigned particular to user.

But now when a users edits his/her own profile, all the available roles are showing up and in fact users can assign roles by themselves and save that. Such users can even edit as admin.

This is obviously not correct, so what should I do to correct that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `/admin/people/permissions/roles` Add a new role, Ex call it Admin2

Then assing that user the Admin2 role

In `/admin/people/permissions` for the Admin2 Column.

Under User:

- Administer permissions
- Administer users

Make sure both of these are unchecked.

For all the other permissions, basically you check mark all the stuff you would like to allow Admin2 to do and leave uncheck all permissions you don't want him to have.

Comment: please tell me where to assign the roles , i have roles and when walk through people->permission here how to asaign?

Comment: and under user administer permission and administers users are unchecked

Comment: you need to go to `/admin/people` then click edit button that corresponds to the user name. Then under Roles check mark the role you want them to have and save changes.

Comment: if i walk through admin people i will find list of users ->if i click on edit than all the roles i could see?user should see only his role assigned,now after disabling the permission when i login as a user the assigned role by admin is only not visible for me

Comment: Go to admin/people/permissions as No Sssweat said. And assign proper permission as @ No Sssweat mentioend. Just keep those settings enabled to administrator. Leave unchecked for all other users.

Comment: @yuvika, yes only the Administrator role can see the roles in the edit user page. If you want to tell users what role they are, you can show them their role in their user page. You can accomplish this programmatically or using views. I suggest you create a new question for this.

Comment: @NoSssweat: thank you so much, i will consider ur words